# Fixed items - Non renewing Subscription

Tags: iphone, ios, ios4

I am having the below queries on implementing the in-app purchase.Actually my content is Songs which totally contains 500 nos.Can i offer this content via non renewing subscription.

Also is there any restrictions to offer content via Non renewing subscription? is there any rules like contents which are periodically updated only can use non renewing subscription?

It is really confusing me , Please let me know.

Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think there is any limitation for Non-renewing subscriptions. Its based on how you providing your service. [Spotify](http://www.spotify.com/int/) is a perfect example for your scenario.

But as a user think of that i purchased a set of 500 songs which should be renewed in 30days? I would rather prefer Non-consumable IAP.